# Programmatically add log information in all renderings (controller, view) HTML

Tags: presentation, mvc, pipelines

Is there an option to write some logging information, like rendering name and data-source location, in every view programmatically, without go and modified in all views?

Comment: What do you mean by *"go and modified"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen manually edit all the cshtml files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by the following way.

**Configuration:**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <mvc.renderRendering>
        <processor type="YourAssembly.LogExecuteRenderer, YourAssembly" patch:instead="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
      </mvc.renderRendering>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**Code to render at the beginning of the rendering:**

```
public class LogExecuteRenderer : ExecuteRenderer
{
    protected override bool Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
    {
        writer.WriteLine($"<div renderingPath=\"{args.Rendering.RenderingItemPath}\" datasource=\"{args.Rendering.DataSource}\"></div>");

        return base.Render(renderer, writer, args);
    }
}
```

**Code to render at the end of the rendering:** (thanks for the comment @MarekMusielak)

```
public class LogExecuteRenderer : ExecuteRenderer
{
    protected override bool Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
    {
        var baseResult = base.Render(renderer, writer, args);

        writer.WriteLine($"<div renderingPath=\"{args.Rendering.RenderingItemPath}\" datasource=\"{args.Rendering.DataSource}\"></div>");

        return baseResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: You open a `<div>` tag in your snippet and then close `</code>` tag. You may want to change this ;) You may also want to write to `writer` where the component ends: save result of `base.Render` to a variable, write component end info to writer and return the result. Anyway, good answer.

Comment: @MarekMusielak that's right, thx! :) I include the second option as well in my answer if you don't mind.